# Know how many entries a key has in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I couldn't find this solution anywhere, must be simple.

Say you have a dictionary with lists

```
test = {'foo' : ['foo1', 'foo2'], 'foo3' : ['foo4', 'foo5', 'foo6']}
```

How can I count how many entries the foo key on test has?

IE the answer for `'foo'` would be '2' or for `'foo3'` would be '3'.

Comment: Are `foo`s variable? Is this valid python code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is a dictionary the foo key has one and only on entry in the dictionary.

However the value corresponding to the foo key is a list. That list has a length

e.g.

```
print( len(test['foo']))
```

Comment: +1 for saying that a key in python's `dict`ionary can have only `0` or `1` occurrences. It's 2nd time in two days someone makes this mistake.

Comment: As you can see by my wording, I'm not exactly Skeet. And, yes, I meant to see how many entries the list that is found with the key 'foo' has. Cheers to the help inbound avalanche!

Answer (score 1):

as easy as

```
print len(test['foo'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy:

```
test = {'foo' : ['foo1', 'foo2'], 'foo3' : ['foo4', 'foo5', 'foo6']}
len(test['foo'])      
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good way, making a dictionary of length, and providing an 'answer':

```
>>> test = {'foo' : ['foo1', 'foo2'], 'foo3' : ['foo4', 'foo5', 'foo6']}
>>> lengths = {k:len(v) for k, v in test.items()}
>>> lengths['foo']
2
```

Also keep in mind that a dictionary can only store a single value for each key. What you're having is not *multiple entries*, but one list with multiple items :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the count dynamically, in case you don't know the key names then try this -

```
test = {'foo' : ['foo1', 'foo2'], 'foo3' : ['foo4', 'foo5', 'foo6']}
for key in test:
    print len(test[key])
#2
#3
```

The use case could be like find the 'key' which has maximum number of elements.